# Dynamic bundle extending with Symfony

Tags: php, class, symfony, bundle, extend

I need to create a website with Synfony with core functionality and multiple additions for specific clients.
From here, nothing too complicated : every client has its own Bundle that extends the core bundle.

The thing is : I want to handle multiple version of the Core Bundle (ie the current version, the next stable version and the beta version) and I want client to be able to chose the core version he's using only with *a cookie* (two people from the same client could use two different core bundle versions).

My question is : is it possible to extend classes and bundle dynamically with Symfony (here, depending on a cookie) ? And more generally : What king of approach can I use to achieve what I have described ?

I would like to use APC (so no `eval` or stuff like that)

Thanks

Comment: You cannot extend classes dynamically with PHP, so no, you cannot do so in Symfony either... Why can you not handle different versions of your core bundle by revision/commit tag and handle it with Composer from there?

Comment: @Gerry sounds like the OP wants to offer the option to select the stability, to the end user - dynamically adding bundles into the kernel.